# NodeJS - inicializar variáveis e elas estarem disponíveis em todo o projeto

Tags: node.js, require

Estou com a seguinte dificuldade:

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o meu `server.js` é o start do projeto.
Entretanto, dentro dos `services, models`, etc eu tenho algumas `libs`, como por exemplo `log` que de acordo com o environment ele mostra no console ou vai para um arquivo de log.

Então aqui tenho 2 itens a questionar e pedir a ajuda de vocês:
1 - eu preciso colocar o `require` na lib de `log` em todos os arquivos? eu sei que existe o `global.` , mas no **vscode**, ele não mostra o escopo. Só mostra com `const, var ou let`.

Veja o exemplo abaixo com `global.` e com `const`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

com global mostra o escopo do server

-

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e com global o tipo é any

2 - essa função que tenho na log, que é a setEnv(env) eu também preciso setar em todos os arquivos?

Comment: Quase nunca é uma boa ideia utilizar variáveis globais pela aplicação. Vale muito mais a pena você criar um módulo e utilizá-lo como tal: importá-lo onde precisar.

Comment: então sua sugestão é ter um modulo tipo env.js que vai inicializar todas essas condicoes?

Comment: outra coisa...sei que foge um pouco da pergunta original, mas qual a melhor forma de lidar com os relative paths?